# How to Set a data type for a textbox

Tags: c#, sql

I'm building a small application that is connected to a private database. In my application, I input data inside textboxes that record data inside a database after clicking a button. The problem I'm facing is that I want to make a certain textbox accept only Integers to prevent entering wrong types of data.

Comment: Are you using winforms or wpf.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like below it will help you...

The below code accepts only `Numbers` and `dots(.)`

**Designer.CS**

```
this.txtNumbers.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.txtNumbers_KeyPress);
```

**Code Behind :**

```
private void txtNumbers_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
        && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)
        && e.KeyChar != '.')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    if (e.KeyChar == '.'
        && (sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

**to Handle Copy and Paste...**

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int result;
    if (txtNumbers.Text != "")
    {
        if (!int.TryParse(txtNumbers.Text, out result))
        {
            txtNumbers.Text = "";
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Integer");                    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note might want to look up decimal separator, instead of hard coding it to '.'

Comment: How well does this handle copy-paste?

Comment: @DanVerdolino : i have changed my code... I have handle copy and paste now..

Answer (score 0):

At it's simplest.

Add a keypress event handler to the textbox

The eventarg argument has the key that was pressed. (`e.KeyChar`)

If it's **not** a legal key set `e.Handled` on the eventargs argument to true.

Don't forget to allow backspace, cut, copy and paste etc through.
If you want negatives, minus sign is allowed but only as the first character.

If you want formatting / formatted display, e.g. negatives in brackets, thousand separators, decimal separators, currency symbols etc, better off knocking up a user control and wrap it all up in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a control designed for numbers, `NumericUpDown`. It gives you added control over decimal places and min / max.